# MYSQL - Campo creado por partes de otros campos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estoy aprendiendo mysql y tengo una duda:
 tengo una tabla alumno con los campos nombre, apellido, añoingreso,número de lista y centro al que pertenece, quería saber como crear un campo que sería mi ID compuesto por la primera letra del nombre, la primera letra del apellido los últimos digitos del año, número de lista y el centro algo así

```
NOMBRE:JOSE 
APELLIDO: PEREZ 
CENTRO : 4 
AÑO :2019
Numero_lista: 1 
CARNET: 04JP1901
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si compartes lo que llevas hecho hasta el momento tu pregunta quedaria mucho mejor y ademas sera mas facil ayudarte. Un saludo :)

Answer (score 1):

tendrías que crear una función almacenada que retorne el valor de los campos numericos de dos digitos añadiendo 0 cuando ese valor sea inferior a 10. 
Luego crear un procedimiento usando la funcion mysql substring() recortando los campos de caracteres, y concatenarlos con la función mysql CONCAT().